issue with Waiting for schema metadata lock and Freeing items getting stuck
I am having an issue important databases into a new Mariadb Galera cluster, it keeps getting hung on this line. I was having issues with the innodb pool size so I upped it to what the old cluster required, I also added a lot of memory. I am not sure what is causing this to hang, can anyone help me?
MariaDB [(none)]> show processlist;
+-----+-------------+-----------+--------------------+---------+------+----------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Id  | User        | Host      | db                 | Command | Time | State                            | Info                                                                                                 | Progress |
+-----+-------------+-----------+--------------------+---------+------+----------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|   1 | system user |           | NULL               | Sleep   | 4738 | wsrep aborter idle               | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
|   2 | system user |           |                    | Sleep   | 2724 | Waiting for schema metadata lock | alter database `citation_index` CHARACTER SET utf8                                                   |    0.000 |
| 547 | root        | localhost | citation_index     | Query   | 2724 | Freeing items                    | INSERT INTO `vectors` VALUES (1033886,'[0.039515189826488495,-0.03698547184467316,0.0510983131825923 |    0.000 |
| 550 | root        | localhost | NULL               | Query   |    0 | starting                         | show processlist                                                                                     |    0.000 |
| 807 | root        | localhost | information_schema | Sleep   | 2600 |                                  | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
+-----+-------------+-----------+--------------------+---------+------+----------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Type: InnoDB
  Name: 
Status: 
=====================================
2024-05-31 12:03:18 0x7fef7c13c640 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 55 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 27 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 4764 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 4791
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 967581
Purge done for trx's n:o < 967579 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 0
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION (0x7fef9ac3e680), not started
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION (0x7fef9ac3db80), not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
--------
FILE I/O
--------
Pending flushes (fsync): 0
18246 OS file reads, 913003 OS file writes, 14403 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 101.00 writes/s, 1.00 fsyncs/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 481909696379
Log flushed up to   481909696379
Pages flushed up to 481118331328
Last checkpoint at  481118297614
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 153578635264
Dictionary memory allocated 911765208
Buffer pool size   9280960
Free buffers       8297736
Database pages     983224
Old database pages 362967
Modified db pages  72290
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.779
Max dirty pages percent: 90.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0
Pages made young 168, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 18112, created 965442, written 893163
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 99.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 983224, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[5940]:cur[990], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 read views open inside InnoDB
state: sleeping
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================

1 row in set (0.001 sec)

I have tried more memory, as the cluster nodes would fail previously. The nodes are stable now and increased innodb_buffer_pool_size
